# Is it possible to use the alfresco forms service to create input fields for a custom webscript or dashlet

Tags: forms, alfresco, alfresco-share

The [forms engine in alfresco share](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Forms_Developer_Guide) seems to be a very powerful way for creating and editing new content objects. Is it possible to use this declarative configuration also for forms that don't directly correspond to repository objects?

The problem I'm trying to solve is a search mask for some custom properties. One of the search fields is for an aspect with a list constraint, and it would be great if alfresco could automatically create the corresponding select element and validations, like it does when editing the objects properties.

As an example, consider the following content model:

```
<constraints>
    <constraint name="jh:listconstraint" type="LIST">
        <parameter name="allowedValues">
            <list>
                <value>100</value>
                <value>200</value>
                <value>300</value>
            </list>
        </parameter>
    </constraint>
    <constraint name="jh:regexConstraint" type="REGEX">
        <parameter name="expression">
            <value>[a-z]{4}</value>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="requiresMatch">
            <value>true</value>
        </parameter>
    </constraint>
</constraint>

<aspects>
    <aspect name="jh:test">
        <properties>
            <property name="jh:property1">
                <title>Property 1</title>
                <type>d:int</type>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint ref="jh:listconstraint"/>
                </constraints>
            </property>
            <property name="jh:property2">
                <title>Property 2</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint ref="jh:regexConstraint"/>
                </constraints>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </aspect>
</aspects>
```

The property sheet for a document having this aspect contains a nice drop down selection for the property with list constraint and automatic validation for the regex constraint. I would like to render the same input fields inside a custom dashlet, but handle the backend logic myself.

The target version would be alfresco 4.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a reasonable way to build up the search (form) based on type- or aspect definitions without severely hurting form CRUD-semantics and ugly `FormsService` hacks in the repo.

If you want to leverage Alfresco Forms, I would try an action-based form documented on the wiki at 
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Custom_Actions . You may still have to worry about dealing with value constraints and you may have to repeat yourself, but it should still give you a decent start.